# JQuery Dialog Load Page Containing Javascript Code

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am loading a Partial View in a Dialog box that contains Javascript.  When the partial view is displayed in the Dialog box, the partial view shows up, but any Javascript that was in the partial view is not there.

*My question: How do I load the Javascript that is on the Partial View?*

**Here is my Javascript file**:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    BindEvents();
});

function BindEvents()
{
    $('#Reassign').bind('click', function (event, ui) {
    GetReassign();
    return false;
    });

function GetReassign() {
    var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
    if (checkeditems) 
    {
        $("#DialogBox").dialog({
            width: 525,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load('/ControllerName/PartialView', function () {
                    var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
                    $('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
                });
            },
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

**Here is my Partial View:**

```
@model SFB.SVP2.Objects.InterviewFollowup
@using SVP2UI.Helpers;

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ddlMailCodes;
    var ddlEmployees;

    function pageLoad() {
        ddlEmployees = $get("AssignedTo");
        ddlMailCodes = $get("MailCodes");
        $addHandler(ddlMailCodes, "change", bindOptions);
        bindOptions();
    }

    function bindOptions() {
        ddlEmployees.options.length = 0;
        var MC = ddlMailCodes.value;
        if (MC) {
            Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke(
                "/Services/BranchService.asmx",
                "Employees",
                false,
                { MC: MC },
                bindOptionResults
            );
        }
    }

    function bindOptionResults(data) {
        var newOption;
        for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
            newOption = new Option(data[k].LastName + ", " + data[k].FirstName, data[k].ADUser);
            ddlEmployees.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }

</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ReassignPost", "InterviewFollowup"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Re-Assign Task</strong></legend>

    <input type="hidden" value="" id="tasks" class="tasks" name="tasks" />

    <div style="display: table; float:left; position:relative; width: 50%">
        <div class="editor-label">
            Location:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("MailCodes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["MailCode"], "-- Select --")
            @Html.ValidationMessage("MailCodes")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: table; float:right; position:relative; width: 50%">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedTo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select name="AssignedTo" id="AssignedTo"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Notes:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" name="Notes" id="Notes" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Notes") 
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Added the Partial View @Dismissile

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. What does the first javascript have to do with anything?

Comment: The first Javascript loads a JQuery Dialog box when a button is clicked. (I am not showing the main view with the button.) When you click on the button, the Dialog box loads.

Comment: When a PartialView (or any page for that matter) is loaded into the JQuery Dialog, it looks as if it strips out all <script> tags! Is there anyway to get around this?  I have a JS tag I need to put on the page, but will get errors if the elements are not loaded.  So I can't put it on the main page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not stripping out the <script> tags; I've done this plenty of times using partial views and AJAX.  Try putting an `alert("hello")` in your script, and see if that gets called.

Comment: I looked at your code and it looks like you are expecting pageLoad to be executed after jquery ui dialog loaded. It will not execute I think (jquery ui does not know about ms ajax). Instead of using pageLoad, use $(function() {}); in your partial view script. But better use jquery alone, for what you doing you don't need ms ajax.

Comment: @EthanBrown -- The alert gets called, but then it's no where in the source of the PartialView when viewing it in Firebug.  Therefore, if I have a <script src=""> tag on my Partial View, it is being stripped and the elements on my partial view don't work  because there is no <script src=""> tag.  I can't put it on the Main view because if I do, I get an error because the JS file is expecting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to externalize all your javascript into a separate js file. Mixing javascript and markup is bad. Once you have externalized it, you can call whatever function you like once you show the partial:

```
$("#DialogBox").dialog({
    width: 525,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    open: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).load('/ControllerName/PartialView', function () {
             // OK, at this stage the partial is injected into the DOM
             // here you can call whatever function you like
             // for example the pageLoad(); function

             var checkeditems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedObjects"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val() }).get().join(",");
             $('input.tasks').val(checkeditems);
        });
    },
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Oh, and is there any reason for still using MicrosoftAjax scripts? Those are so much obsolete compared to jQuery that it's been long time I've seen someone using them. You can perfectly fine invoke a script enabled .ASMX service using jQuery.